# How to setup hot reloading in React Native on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

Reloading in the iPhone Simulator works just fine, but when I want to load new javascript to the app on physical device, I always need to build and deploy the app from Xcode.

Is there some step I forgot to do?

Also, [My In-App Developer Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXOHC.png) seems to be lacking some items. Shouldn't I be able to enable `Live Reloading` in there as well?

- React Native: 0.41.2
- Xcode: 8.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need to be on the same Wifi with both your iPhone and your Mac. The connection with the React Packager doesn't go through the USB.

At least being connected to different networks was my problem.

Comment: Worked for me. But first, I needed to setup the phone with the IP of my Mac: 1) shake phone, 2) Select Configure Bundler. No source code changes required (as stated in other answers).